# Sum cells option does not appear in Excel's Quick Analysis Tool

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

- I past values in Excel Spreadsheet (single column from a PowerPoint
  table).
- I select the cells in Excel, and a little icon appears at bottom
  right of selection.
- I click that icon, options appear, I go to `Totals` Tab I only see two options there, both says `Count` with different icons.

Why don't the `Sum` and other options appear so I can sum the column easily?

[image]

Comment: Because the cells are numbers stored as text.  You need to convert them to true numbers.  BTW, just changing the format of the cell will not accomplish this.

Comment: @ScottCraner It seemed promising but that doesn't seem to be the case. I have multiple columns in same table. If paste column one column, I get `Sum` option, if I paste the other, I don't. The data is all numbers, very same (most is identical). Total only 9 rows so I know the data.

Answer (score 0):

I got in this weird situation when I copied data from a table in PowerPoint. Even though it's all numbers, the Quick Analysis Tool I get is the same as if the cells were text fields (no math functions).

**Problem**

And this issue was not that the cell should have be numeric type, this operation works on general cell format. Excel automatically knows if the data is numeric.

The problem was hidden characters in the data due to which excel sees the value as text. This can be noted as the cell values are **left aligned** as in text, excel automatically **right align** numbers. So if you see left aligned numbers, that's a flag, excel thinks it's text.

**Solution**

- We need to clear the hidden character which could have come as result of formatting. Select the cells and clear formating (Home tab >> Editing > Clear -> 'Clear Formats'). That should do.
- If you select all cells and select Normal cell type, that should do as well.
- But if the above doesn't work, create a new column adjacent to the data, enter first two entries manually and use flash fill and it copies all the rows and removes the hidden characters.

**Good To Know**

- Copying the column data to notepad or notepad++ and back doesn't remove the hidden characters, they do get copied.
- If you modified the cell data with hidden character and press enter, it will clear the bad character.
- You edit the cell with bad data only one character at a time if you want to change the data but retain the formating. Select one character (highlight selection) and type new one character, this replaces just that one character doesn't seem to alter anything else in the cell value :)

[image]